# Post data not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, post

I created a asp.net project in visual studio.
I have a default page with a **site.master.**
Idea is, that a thirdparty is calling me, with post data.
Problem, i cant see/access the post data.

Testpage i use to send post data:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="Default.aspx" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input id="targetusername" name="targetusername" type="text" value="Student" />
        <br />
        <input id="targetmobile" name="targetmobile" type="text" value="076318xxxx" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="callportal" value="press me" />   
    </form>

<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Firefox","requestId":"f242563534b547c8adff38f9df3c8092"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:59240/e0c4688428cc4a5b9f9fb58ab460d3a4/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

In the Default.aspx.cs i have this code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //check for POST data
        if (Request.Form["targetusername"] == null || Request.Form["targetmobile"] == null )
        {
            this.lblErrors.Text = "Failed, post data not according our expectations.";
            return;
        }
```

But when i set a brakepoint and check for this:

```
Request.Form["targetusername"]
Request.Form.HasKeys()
Master.Page.Request.Form.HasKeys()
```

They all indicate that there is no post data around ....

I'm new to asp.net do i have to active post data somewhere?
Do i look in the wrong variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stripped the html to the minimum, like html should be anyway.

The Forms

```
enctype="text/plain" or enctype="text/plain"
```

or

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

causes the problem. Without enctype, its fine. Also it looks like the action has to be

```
action="Default"
```

with this one its not working:

```
action="Default.aspx"
```

So, it works now with this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Miauww</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="Default">
        Username<br />
        <input name="targetusername" type="text" value="Student" />
        <br />
        <br />
        Mobile<br />
        <input name="targetmobile" type="text" value="076318xxxx" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="press me" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```